# Momentjs Keep all milliseconds digits from a postgresql timestamp

Tags: node.js, postgresql, momentjs, knex.js, milliseconds

I have a Postgresql database.
In one table I have the field **insertTime** it's a timestamp without timezone.
So the format is like:

> YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS...
> *(The milliseconds digit numbers is varying from value to value*)

From a NodeJs service I have a cached maxInsertTime.

Periodically, I get the new records from this cached value (**knex "^0.20.13"**)

> WHERE insertTime > cachedInsertTime

And recalculate the maxInsertTime of the returned records (**moment "^2.27.0"**):

> moment.max( [ array_of_insertTime ] )

it returns a date with format:

> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ

Sometimes I lose some milliseconds digits:

Example my maxInsertTime is 2020-08-22T11:22:30.45354 but moment.max always return me 2020-08-22T11:22:30.453Z, it leave only 3 milliseconds digits and add a Z.

So after when I when to select all the insertTime > cachedInsertTime, I have:

> 2020-08-22T11:22:30.45354 > 2020-08-22T11:22:30.453Z  // witch is true (but don't want this value to fit in the where clause)

How can I do to keep all the milliseconds digits same from the database?

Thanks.

Comment: you can override with pg-types returning of timestamp type to be a string, so it wont be converted to Date() object.

Comment: Yes excellent I found that solution today I can make setters and getters with pg-types :)